# Construct the unitaries U by decomposition in TSP Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises

[image]

I'm stuck in here and really don't understand this stuff. In order to construct the unitary matrices for Quantum Phase Estimation, Qiskit decomposes the diagonal unitary matrices U(j) by tensor product two 2x2 matrices(P-gates form) and element-wise with the 4x4 matrices(Controlled-T form). I really can't get the techniques to decompose in this term with the value e^i(c-a) or e^i(d+c-a-b). How can they get it? By any formula or by trial and error? Please enlight me

https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-paper-implementations/tsp.html